# If else condition in LINQ to XML query in c#

Tags: linq

this is xml let say:

`<.Sections>
<.SECTION ID ="4" NAME="GetStudents" CONTROL-TYPE="Button" LINK="WebForm2.aspx">`

```
      </SECTION>
      <.SECTION ID="5" NAME="SelectStudent" CONTROL-TYPE="Drowpdown" METHOD ="selectList_MethodName">

      </SECTION>
```

Observe this xml, I am generating the UI controls base on "CONTROL-TYPE" Attributes. but there are different attributes are there in both sections elements. as LINK and METHOD . I want to query like this , if section's CONTROL-TYPE=="Button" then get value of LINK attribute Else If CONTROL-TYPE=="Drowpdown" then get value of METHOD attribute Else If.

I am trying to write code in c# +ASP.net. how to achieve this? is there way get such data ?

NOTE: please don't go on dot inside tag as <.SECTION>. it is for this forum page understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simplest way is either an explicit if/else:

```
string value;
string controlType = (string) element.Attribute("CONTROL-TYPE");
if (controlType == "Button")
{
    value = (string) element.Attribute("LINK");
}
else if (controlType == "Dropdown")
{
    value = (string) element.Attribute("METHOD");
}
else
{
    // What do you want to happen if it's neither of these?
}
```

... or use the conditional operator if you're happy with a simple default value for other control types:

```
string controlType = (string) element.Attribute("CONTROL-TYPE");
string value = controlType == "Button" ? (string) element.Attribute("LINK")
             : controlType == "Dropdown" ? (string) element.Attribute("METHOD")
             : "default value";
```

EDIT: Within a query expression, there are two reasonable ways to do this. First, you could use the conditional operator and a `let` clause to fetch the control type just once:

```
var query = 
     from element in elements
     let controlType = (string) element.Attribute("CONTROL-TYPE")
     select new {
         ID = (string) element.Attribute("ID"),
         XYZ = controlType == "Button" ? (string) element.Attribute("LINK")
             : controlType == "Dropdown" ? (string) element.Attribute("METHOD")
            : "default value"
     };
```

Alternatively - and preferrably, IMO - put this logic into a method, and then call the method from the select clause:

```
var query = 
     from element in elements
     let controlType = (string) element.Attribute("CONTROL-TYPE")
     select new {
         ID = (string) element.Attribute("ID"),
         XYZ = GetXyz(element);
     };

...
private static void GetXyz(XElement element)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: wo..wo.. is this i have to write in Select of Linq ? I think it is not support to declaration variables like string u did here ... please tell me where should i have to write this logic ?
let say I ave select as :

//code started here...
from mimic in....something..
select new
{
 ID = mimic.Attribute("ID"),
NAME = mimic.Attribute("NAME"),
CONTROLTYPE = mimic.Attribute("CONTROL-TYPE"),
 //I want to wrte here logic..... for Value as per your code

Comment: @Lalit: It would have helped if you'd given the context beforehand... will edit.